# What manga is this image of "Charlotte inside the game" from?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I have tried reverse searching the image multiple times, but nothing has come up.

[image]

*"young woman was reincarnated into a villianess into an otome game named charlotte ebony"*

Comment: Because of the image description, I thought it might be "*Because of Her Love for Sake, the Otome Game Setting Was Broken and the Villainous Noblewoman Became the Noblewoman With Cheats*" but I can't see a matching panel, although the heroine does look very similar indeed.

Comment: FWIW, I have tried searching for a character named "Charlotte Ebony" in Japanese, but it returned 0 result (or I failed in transliterating it correctly).

Answer (score 8):

This is *[Midareru Dress ni Takeru Yokubou](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=193275)* (AKA *Raging Lust as He Tears off My Dress*).

The main character is a woman who was reincarnated into the otome game "Ayase's Fiora". She tries to be the heroine, but no one much likes her, so she decides become a villain and ends the game by being exiled.

The scene you are looking for is from the 4th chapter, shortly after Charlotte Ebony is sentenced to exile.

[image]

Comment: Fair warning, this is not a SFW manga

Comment: +1 from me. How did you find it?

Comment: @Valorum - I did a search using the full text from the original image and spotted the panel in the images tab funnily enough.

Comment: Interesting. I did much the same and got nothing but false-positives.